# Displaying Dates from MongoDB with Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I saved few datasets to MongoDB using mongoose.js. But I got a problem with displaying them on an html site using express.js and ejs.

Here is my scenario:

**Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    creationTime: Date,
    modificationTime: Date,
    title: String
});
var Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
module.exports.Item = Item;
```

**Route:**

```
app.get('/item/:id', function(req, res) {

    Item.findById(req.params.id, function(err, doc){

        console.log(doc); //This check displays everything correctly on console

        res.render('item.html.ejs', {
            item : doc
        });
    });
});
```

**View:**

```
<h1><%= item.title %>:</h1>
<p>Creation: <%= item.creationDate %></p>
<p>Modification: <%= item.modificationDate %></p>
```

The result of this setting is that title is being displayed correctly while both dates are `undefined`.

I assume it has something to do with MongoDB's ISODate format. But I can't find a solution on how to convert it for displaying in html views.

I appreciate your help. Cheers

Comment: I don't think it is about MongoDB's date format, but if you wish you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to convert it to a more readable format

Comment: You can use moment.js in node.

Comment: Seriously? I get downvoted for this question? What is this? Reddit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just copied and pasted the code the solution is very very simple.

In your model you defined creation`Time` and modification`Time` in your template you try to access item.creation`Date` and item.modification`Date`.

After that change you should be able to see something other then undefined, but you probably still need to convert this into a proper date format.

Comment: Sometimes in life you ask yourself if you are completely retarded -.- Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 9):

I have the following helpers using moment.js in my projects.

```
date: function(date){
  moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
},
fromNow: function(date){
  moment(date).fromNow()
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the tip. It's a very nice helper :-)

Answer (score 1):

I add an ejs filter using the example above, but I had to change it a little bit to get it to work:

Create the 'created_at' attribute on the mongoose schema and automatically create it on save():

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name    : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
  , created_at    : { type: Date }
});


ItemSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  if ( !this.created_at ) {
    this.created_at = new Date;
  }
  next();
});
```

Install moment (and write to package.json)

```
npm install moment --save
```

Add the filter in app.js or wherever else you define filters for ejs:

```
var moment = require('moment');

ejs.filters.fromNow = function(date){
  return moment(date).fromNow()
}
```

Use the filter in page.ejs

```
<span class="created_at"><%=: item.created_at | fromNow %></span>
```